# Django CBV AttributeError: Generic detail view must be called with either an object pk or a slug

Tags: python, django, tdd

I'm trying to get the output of a class based view in a test.

```
factory = RequestFactory()
request = factory.get(item.get_absolute_url()) # get_absolute_url returns '/my-slug-path/'
request.user = UserFactory(username='test', is_staff=False, is_superuser=False)
item_view = ItemDetail.as_view()
response = item_view(request)
```

When I run the above code, it errors out on `item_view(request)`.

```
*** AttributeError: Generic detail view ItemDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

How can I make this work?  The CBV works fine in normal site operation, but while writing the test it fails at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is calling the view directly, rather than going through Django's URL resolver/dispatcher. So you need to pass the arguments the view is expecting: in this case, as the error message says, including the slug/pk. So:

```
response = item_view(request, item.slug)
```

However, a much better way to test views is to use the built-in test client object, which means you can get rid of *all* of that code and replace it with just this:

```
response = self.client.get(item.get_absolute_url())
```

Comment: Your 2nd option is much better.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this was changed in a later version of Django, but as of 1.7.11 I had to do `response = item_view(request, slug=item.slug)` (that is, the slug is passed in as a keyword argument). This matters if you need to set something on the request (such as the user).